# How often do animals respawn in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was recently playing Minecraft Pocket Edition in a world I have specially designated for hunting, and I was wondering, how often do animals respawn in MCPE? I know for a fact that they have to, otherwise you'd have a lifeless empty world after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears that animals in MCPE **do** respawn after a while. This will only apply to passive animals that have been previously killed, such as, sheep, cows, chickens, pigs, etc. I believe the amount of time it takes for them to respawn is random though. Hope thi helps!

Comment: Can you please provide some reference?

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question but it's worth mentioning.

Animals rarely "re-spawn" in the normal Minecraft. Most animals you see spawn with newly generated chunks. That is, when you visit an area for the first time, animals are likely to spawn. However, re-spawning in an already visited area is rare.

> Approximately one in ten newly generated chunks will contain mobs,
> usually in packs of up to four of the same species. They will always
> spawn on the highest available block in a column i.e. the one that can
> see the sky. For an animal to spawn on it, this block must be opaque and...
>
> Very rarely, new animals can spawn in already generated chunks, just
> like monsters do. When animals spawn in this way, they do so only on
> grass blocks with light level 9 or greater above them. This is also a
> requirement for animals spawning from monster spawners. Unlike
> monsters, animals do not spontaneously despawn, except for wild
> ocelots and wolves (which can despawn only when they are hostile).

This leaves us with the question of whether the spawning behavior in Pocket Edition is any different.

Reference: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawning#Animal_spawning)

Comment: I'm probably going to believe most of these spawning characteristics apply to MCPE.